# Displaying XML Child Data with PHP and SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml

I am new to PHP as well as XML.  I am attempting to pull specific elements from what I believe are child elements of the XML file.

The main class is `<events>` and there are multiple `<event>` within the `<events>` class.  I am trying to pull specific data from the XML file and display them.

```
<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://xml.pinnaclesports.com/pinnaclefeed.aspx?sporttype=Football&sportsubtype=nfl');
foreach($xml->children() as $event){
    echo $event->participants->participant->participant_name . ", ";
    echo $event->participants->participant[1]->participant_name . ", ";
    echo $event->periods->period->spread->spread_visiting . ", ";
    echo $event->periods->period->total->over_adjust . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Here is the output, with no PHP error_log entries:

```
, , ,
, , ,
, , ,
, , ,
```

I appreciate any and all help.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_simplexml_get.asp

Comment: I was actually using that to construct the PHP pull, however, I think with how the data in the XML file is nested is causing the results not to be properly pulled, but I cannot figure out how to pull from the nested data.

Answer (score 0):

To access nested elements, you can simply follow element path starting from the context element (`event`) to the target element. It will be a lot easier to see the path/hierarchy if you format the XML properly :

```
foreach($xml->children() as $event) {
    echo $event->participants->participant->participant_name . ", ";
    echo $event->participants->participant[1]->participant_name . ", ";
    echo $event->periods->period->spread->spread_visiting . ", ";
    echo $event->periods->period->total->over_adjust . "<br>";
}
```

**<kbd>[`eval.in demo`](https://eval.in/658384)</kbd>**

**output :**

```
Denver Broncos, San Diego Chargers, -3, 101<br>
```

Comment: Very nice, I understand how to specify the full path to the objects.  It seems to put the XML into a string then modifies the string.  Is where any way to get this working with a 3rd party feed?

Comment: Something like this?

'<?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://xml.feed.coml') or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$xml=simplexml_load_string($raw);
foreach($xml->children() as $event) {
    echo $event->participants->participant->participant_name . ", ";
    echo $event->participants->participant[1]->participant_name . ", ";
    echo $event->periods->period->spread->spread_visiting . ", ";
    echo $event->periods->period->total->over_adjust . "<br>";
}
?>'

Comment: I do not receive PHP errors with this, but results come back blank:

<?php
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://xml.pinnaclesports.com/pinnaclefeed.aspx?sporttype=Football&sportsubtype=nfl');
foreach($xml->children() as $event){
    echo $event->participants->participant->participant_name . ", ";
    echo $event->participants->participant[1]->participant_name . ", ";
    echo $event->periods->period->spread->spread_visiting . ", ";
    echo $event->periods->period->total->over_adjust . "<br>";
}
?>